# ASP.NET Core + Swagger\SwashBuckle UI login with ADFS WS-federation

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I can easily configure SwashBuckle to allow users to login using the Authorize button with the following code

```
  c.AddSecurityDefinition(this.IdentityConfiguration.Type, new OAuth2Scheme
  {
      Type = "",
      Flow = "",
      TokenUrl = "",
      AuthorizationUrl = ""
  });
```

This will load the ADFS login screen and returns a Jwt Token.

However, I haven't been able to find any examples that use ADFS WS-Federation and returns a SAML token.

Is this something that Swagger\SwashBuckle supports?

Answer (score 0):

If we look at the Open API 3.0 spec, we can see the supported types:

> The type of the security scheme. Valid values are "apiKey", "http", "oauth2", "openIdConnect".

So WS-Federation is not supported by the standard.

https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.0.md#securitySchemeObject

2.0 spec says similarly:

> The type of the security scheme. Valid values are "basic", "apiKey" or "oauth2".

https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#security-scheme-object